# Unit testing for a compiler output

Tags: unit-testing, compiler-construction, haskell

As part of a university project, we have to write a compiler for a toy language. In order to do some testing for this, I was considering how best to go about writing something like unit tests. As the compiler is being written in haskell, Hunit and quickcheck are both available, but perhaps not quite appropriate.

How can we do any kind of non-manual testing?
The only idea i've had is effectively compiling to haskell too, seeing what the output is, and using some shell script to compare this to the output of the compiled program - this is quite a bit of work, and isn't too elegant either.

The unit testing is to help us, and isn't part of assessed work itself.

Comment: You don't need to compile to Haskell -- you can also just write a simple reference implementation of an interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really depends on what parts of the compiler you are writing. It is nice if you can keep phases distinct to help isolate problems, but, in any phase, and even at the integration level, it is perfectly reasonable to have unit tests that consist of pairs of source code and hand-compiled code. You can start with the simplest legal programs possible, and ensure that your compiler outputs the same thing that you would if compiling by hand.

As complexity increases, and hand-compiling becomes unwieldy, it is helpful for the compiler to keep some kind of log of what it has done. Then you can consult this log to determine whether or not specific transformations or optimizations fired for a given source program.

Depending on your language, you might consider a generator of random programs from a collection of program fragments (in the QuickCheck vein). This generator can test your compiler's stability, and ability to deal with potentially unforeseen inputs.

Answer (score 3):

The unit tests shall test small piece of code, typically one class or one function. The lexical and semantic analysis will each have their unit tests. The Intermediate Represetation generator will also have its own tests.

A unit test covers a simple test case: it invokes the function to be unit tested in a controlled environment and verify (assert) the result of the function execution. A unit test usually test one behavior only and has the following structure, called AAA :

- Arrange: create the environment the function will be called in
- Act: invoke the function
- Assert: verify the result

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [shelltestrunner](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelltestrunner). Here are some [example tests](http://joyful.com/repos/hledger/tests). It is also being used in [this compiler project](https://github.com/bjpop/berp).

Answer (score 0):

One options is to the approach [this guy is doing](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/EmbeddedInAcademia/~3/GaW0B0UPkIo/289) to test real compilers: get together with as many people as you can talk into it and each of you compiles and runs the same set of programs and then compare the outputs. Be sure to add every test case you use as more inputs makes it more effective. A little fun with automation and source control and you can make it fairly easy to maintain.

Be sure to get it OKed by the prof first but as you will only be sharing test cases and outputs I don't see where he will have much room to object.

Answer (score -1):

Testing becomes more difficult once the output of your program goes to the console (such as standard output). Then you have to resort to some external tool, like `grep` or `expect` to check the output.

Keep the return values from your functions in data structures for as long as possible. If the output of your compiler is, say, assembly code, build a string in memory (or a list of strings) and output it at the last possible moment. That way you can test the contents of the strings more directly and quickly.